# Python on android (kivy) - speed bottlenecks for certain operations?

Tags: android, python, optimization, kivy

I'm fairly far along developing a Kivy app. Its targeted for android, but will also work (simultaneously with a different skin) on desktops and hopefully iOs eventually.

The basic dependencies I'm heavily using are:-

- twisted - using this as an IPC, my app has a server/client
  relationship   between the data manipulation and the UI
- Whoosh - for text search
- xmltodict - for easy XML manipulation

I'm having REALLY long app startup times on android, on a relatively recent phone, which doesn't bode well. From my rough timings (based on time.time() and subtracting from my App's **init** time):-

- My app gets control from kivy startup at about 1 second in
- My initialization of custom classes etc. is done at the 2.4 second mark
- At the 14.4 second mark, I finally complete the bulk of my data loading
- At the 17 second mark, I start sending the data out to the client UI using twisted
- At the 22 second mark, the UI receives the data

There's multiple points I want to address there. For example the roughly 5 second gap for data send can be easily broken into pieces and updated in the UI piecemeal, so I'm keeping that for later, but I need to ask about the long 12 second gap for data loading. This data loading involves creating about a 1000 instances of a custom class, with the following steps (cumulative time over 1000 instances):-

- Reading data from 1000 text XML files (0.734 seconds)
- Parsing the XML in the read data (9.198 seconds)
- Filling the object's variables based on the parsed XML (0.585 seconds)
- Directory tree traversal (use this to locate a certain base folder, 0.0824 seconds)
- mtime measurement for the xml files (0.12 seconds)

The measured timings surprised me, because the equivalent timings for running the same code on my laptop are 0.041, 0.9, 0.062, 0.009, and 0.016). Everything's about 10 times slower.

What, if anything, can I do about this? The phone being used for testing has 3GB of RAM and a Snapdragon 801 processor, so I'm quite worried about using this app on slower/older models. My initial thoughts were that the slow-down was due to sd cards being inherently slower than my laptop's hard disk drive, but the fact that xml parsing (non IO related) took so long seems to indicate processing problems.

Suggestions/criticisms welcome.

Comment: Can you store the data in something more convenient than xml? How about pickle or even json?

Comment: I've considered that, but my base data source needs to be xml for legacy reasons. I'm currently pondering a cache (probably pickled) to be used on startup which gets updated once the data reading thread finds a difference. That just pushes the problem later though...

Comment: see if you can get lxml library, it is compiled and should be much faster. I would definitely cache everything I can as a pickle, even if that cuts down startup time only by a second.

Comment: I've done a quick implementation of just the bottleneck XML code (Reading) in lxml, and it cuts the runtime in half. It's still probably an order of magnitude too slow though, leaving me with 10+ seconds startup time, and this doesn't solve the whole 'why is it so much slower on Android' question.

Comment: I was going to suggest poorly optimized python interpreter/xml module, but since LXML runs natively and is slow as well, then it is something outside python. Maybe move files from SD card to onboard storage.

Comment: Thanks, but the files are already on on board storage, and the numbers for python-only actions like assigning a class's attribute shows a consistent order of magnitude slower performance, so it's not only the IO-related code.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate possibility is that you're just seeing the android processor be slower than the desktop one. I'm not sure what the benchmark comparisons are nowadays, but I've seen this be a problem in the past. That said, I'd have guessed the same as you that the difference shouldn't be that big.

I don't know if it would make a difference, but one general thing to try might be to compile for armeabi-v7a (rather than the default armeabi). This enables hardware floating point calculation, amongst other things. I don't know if it makes a difference in generic apps, but it certainly could. You can target this using the python-for-android master branch with `--arch=armeabi-v7a`, or the `android_new` target in the buildozer master branch (the rest of buildozer operation is the same, and it automatically uses v7a).

Another question would be, do you have access to a more efficient xml parser? If you can find one in e.g. cython rather than python (I don't know what you're using right now), this could make a difference. I see the other alternative of using a more efficient data structure has already been raised in a comment.

Sorry that neither of these suggestions are very specific. If you ask on the kivy support channels you may find someone who's found and resolved similar issues.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the compilation options. My question specifies I'm using xmltodict, and changing that would be a fairly involved task. A last resort due to the amount of work involves.

Comment: I've hacked out using lxml (should be pretty much as fast as possible) and I get roughly 5 seconds for reading, parsing, and creating my objects. Which is better but still 10+ times slower than on the laptop (which got similar speed gains).

Comment: The compilation options give negligible to no result, as far as I can tell with simple benchmarks.